# Is violin used in North Indian Classical music

Tags: indian-classical

Indian classical music can be broadly classified as **Hindustani Classical** (played 
 mostly in northern regions) and **Carnatic music** (played mostly in Southern regions). *Is violin used only in Carnatic music, or it is used in Hindustani Classical as well ?*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the violin is used in both.

The [New World Encyclopedia](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Hindustani_classical_music) page about Hindustani classical music says:

> A number of musical instruments are associated with Hindustani classical music. The veena, a string instrument, was traditionally regarded as the most important, but few play it today and it has largely been superseded by its cousins the sitar and the sarod, both of which owe their origin to Persian influences. Other plucked or struck string instruments include the surbahar, sursringar, santoor and various versions of the slide guitar. **Among bowed instruments, the sarangi, esraj (or dilruba) and violin are popular.** The bansuri (bamboo flute), shehnai and harmonium are important wind instruments. In the percussion ensemble, the tabla and the pakhavaj are the most popular. Various other instruments (including the banjo and the piano) have also been used in varying degrees.

The same is also said on the Hindustani classical music [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindustani_classical_music), however due to the almost identical working it's likely that the source of this information is the New World Encyclopedia:

> A number of musical instruments are associated with Hindustani classical music. The veena, a string instrument, was traditionally regarded as the most important, but few play it today and it has largely been superseded by its cousins the sitar and the sarod, both of which owe their origin to Persian influences. **Among bowed instruments, the sarangi and violin are popular.** The bansuri, shehnai and harmonium are important wind instruments. In the percussion ensemble, the tabla and the pakhavaj are the most popular. Rarely used plucked or struck string instruments include the surbahar, sursringar, santoor, and various versions of the slide guitar. Various other instruments have also been used in varying degrees.

[This answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/54643/32406) to a different question also mentions the use of violin in Hindustani classical, but contains little other relavant information.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aric for your answer. I have been looking for some sources and examples of the presence of Violin in Hindustani Classical Music, but unable to locate the same. Are you aware of any such articles/ notes?

Comment: @user52347 Not without googling it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

However the south has greater use of violin, but north indian classical music also has a violin in instrumental classical music.There are great maestros like Kala Ramnath (from mewati gharana).you can visit below link to view her performances.
http://kalaramnath.com/